# Back up a oracle DB encrypted by TDE

Tags: oracle, backup, tde

I want to back up my encrypted DB by TDE.

So, I run exp command. but I have an errors. because of encrypted table spaces.

is there any way to back up my DB encrypted by TDE??

I don't have a idea.

plz help me.

Comment: You can get start from Oracle documentation. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14191/rcmbackp.htm#BRADV72450

Comment: first of all you have to check whether your wallet was created with auto-login option. If yes then everything should work out of the box. If not you have to unlock TDE tbs.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned you have encrypted DB, you need to have Oracle Wallet open, if we assume db instance is up, is already open.

I do not think you can/should use "exp" utility. It's replaced by more powerful "expdp" and "impdp" utilities. These two utilities will allow you to successful backup/restore encrypted data.

Please look into Oracle Utilities guide for further command line reference. Generally for expdp you need to use ENCRYPTION and ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD and you may or may not use Oracle Wallet.

My preffered way though, to use RMAN.

Comment: You mean that if I use expdp utility with ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD option, then I can backup encrypted data? is it right?